# Show "loading" animation while API is working and show error

Tags: javascript

I am using the below function to fetch some values using API and use the response to populate a drop down.
How can I add a loading animation which prevents interaction with other elements by the user when the API is being invoked.
Also, if any error happens, want to show that as well.

```
window.onload = getPlatforms;



async function getPlatforms()
{
    const response = await fetch(
        'http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_platforms',
        {
            method: 'POST',
        }
    );
    const jdata = await response.json();
    ldata = jdata["final_result"]
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('device_select');
    selectElement.appendChild(new Option("SELECT", "SELECT")).cloneNode(true)
    for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
           selectElement.appendChild(new Option(ldata[i], ldata[i])).cloneNode(true)
    }
    ClearOptionsFast("label_select")
    ClearOptionsFast("baseline_select")
}
```

Comment: Are you using React.js or just HTML, please specify.

Comment: using just HTML

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTML only, toggling CSS properties can be an approach.

```js
async function getPlatforms() {
  document.getElementById("loading-overlay").display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("loader").display = "block";

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_platforms', {
        method: 'POST',
      }
    );
    const jdata = await response.json();
    ldata = jdata["final_result"];
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('device_select');
    selectElement.appendChild(new Option("SELECT", "SELECT")).cloneNode(true);

    for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
      selectElement.appendChild(new Option(ldata[i], ldata[i])).cloneNode(true);
    }
    ClearOptionsFast("label_select");
    ClearOptionsFast("baseline_select");

    document.getElementById("loading-overlay").display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loader").display = "none";
  } catch (_error) {
    document.getElementById("error-div").display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("error-div").innerHTML = _error.message;
  }
}
```

```css
#loading-overlay {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

#loader {
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  /* Your custom loader CSS */
}

#error-div {
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading-overlay">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <p id="error-div"></p>
</div>
```

*Note: This code is for give you an idea of the working, you have to customize it to achieve exactly what you want.*

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a loading state first, declare a variable isLoading and set it to false by default, and in the `getPlatforms` function where you are making a call, just above it set 'isLoading' to true, and when the request was completed which is completed in after response.json(), set 'isLoading' to false there. This is how you can achieve a loading state while making an API call.

Comment: Any code example? thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).